# how do I append a token to a url to pass to curl

Tags: json, bash, shell, curl

In a bash script, when I set:

`myUrl="https://api.site.com/api/v2/export/123456"`

and then run:

`awsAccess=$(curl -X GET $(echo "${myUrl}") \
  --header "Accept: application/json" \
  --header "Authorization: Bearer myAuthCode")`

I get the proper JSON result:

`{"status":"Complete","total_files":1,"completed_files":1,"file_urls":["https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.site.com/task/123456/encoded-file-name.csv?AWSAccessKeyId=myAWSAccessKeyId"]}`

But when I obtain a token like this:

`myToken=$(echo "${content}" | jq -r '.token' <<< "${myAccessJSON}")`

Which sets `myToken=123456`

And I build my URL variable like this:

`baseUrl="https://api.site.com/api/v2/export/"
myUrl=$baseUrl$myToken`

And then I run:

`awsAccess=$(curl -X GET $(echo "${myUrl}") \
  --header "Accept: application/json" \
  --header "Authorization: Bearer myAuthCode")`

I get the following JSON response:

`{"status":"Pending","total_files":1,"completed_files":0,"file_urls":[]}`

Which does not contain the URL I need to download the file I am requesting.  What's even more peculiar is that when I enter the commands above directly into the cli, the token gets appended correctly, and I receive the complete response with the URL I need.  How do I pass the URL concatenated with the token in my cURL request via a shell script?

Comment: What do `echo $myToken` and `echo "${myUrl}"` return if run before your last `curl` command? Also the `GET $(echo "${myUrl}")` looks superfluous; how about `GET ${myUrl}`?

Comment: `jq` can't read from both the pipe and a here string.

Comment: <code>echo $myToken</code> successfully returns the token.

Comment: Hmm... I think you found something Will Cain, where <code>echo $myUrl</code> returns the URL with the token appended, <code>echo "${myUrl}"</code> returns an empty string.  I'm trying your suggestion to use <code>GET ${myUrl}</code> now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I feel a little silly now. It turns out my syntax was fine. What my script does is it connects to a server, requests a token, and then reconnects to that same server to request data.  I was trying to make this happen in a single batch script.  It turns out, the first session was still open when I'd make my second connection to request the data by using the token I received on the first connection.  So, instead of writing the JSON responses to bash session variables, I simply output the response from the first script to a file and end the script, which closes the connection.  I then read that file with a second batch script and open a new connection, and now everything is working.